# Store changes not immediately visible to component due to this error message not showing in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

Store changes not immediately visible to component due to this error message not showing in component whenever request get failed. From reducer, state update take some time to return the update value to component. Hence, component always return as empty msg which is default value present in reducer

Api.js

```
export const createCategory = async (category, authtoken) => {
  return await axios.post(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/category/create`,
    category,
    {
      headers: {
        authtoken,
      },
    }
  );
};
```

category.saga.js

```
export function* createCategoryAsync({ payload: { name, token } }) {
  try {
    yield delay(1000);
    const response = yield call(createCategory, { name }, token);
    yield delay(1000);
    console.log("===response", response);
    if (response.status === 200 && response.status < 300) {
      yield put(createCategorySuccess(response.data.name));
    }
    console.log("===response", response);
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(createCategoryFail(error.response.data));
  }
}
```

category.reducer.js

```
import CategoryActionTypes from "./category.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  categoryName: "",
  categories: [],
  error: false,
  errorMsg: "",
};

const categoryReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CategoryActionTypes.LOAD_CATEGORY_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case CategoryActionTypes.LOAD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        categories: action.payload,
      };
    case CategoryActionTypes.SET_CATEGORY_EMPTY:
      return {
        ...state,
        categoryName: "",
      };
    case CategoryActionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORY_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case CategoryActionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        categoryName: action.payload,
      };
    case CategoryActionTypes.LOAD_CATEGORY_FAIL:
    case CategoryActionTypes.CREATE_CATEGORY_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: true,
        errorMsg: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default categoryReducer;
```

Component.js

```
const Component = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        loadCateories();
      }, []);
  const { categories, loading, categoryName, error, errorMsg } = useSelector(
    (state) => ({
      ...state.category,
    })
  );

  const loadCateories = () => {
    dispatch(loadCategoryStart());
  };

  console.log("==errorMsg", errorMsg);

  const {
    user: { token },
  } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // setLoading(true);
    // dispatch(setCategoryEmpty());
    dispatch(createCategoryStart({ name, token }));
    if (categoryName) {
      toast.success(`${name} is created`);
      setName("");
      loadCateories();
    } else {
      toast.error(errorMsg && errorMsg);
      setName("");
    }
     
  };
```

}

Comment: try catch always works

Comment: I have change the question. Do you have any solution for the above problem ?